# Can I use known YouTube video cartoon characters on an educational children app?

Tags: copyright

I'm developing a children app to teach vocabulary, how to talk and to read. I have different categories (23 at the moment) and around 400 items so far. I though in using a Characters category and include many known children characters, such as Peppa Pig, Paw Patrol, etc, maybe marvel and DC characters, etc. Just to teach how to read and speak the words.

I saw this "US copyright law provides an exemption for fair use, allowing portions of copyrighted works to be incorporated into original works for demonstrative or educational purposes."

This use is clearly educational, as I'm helping teaching children how to read and say aloud these characters.

Would that be possible? Would google or apple not approve the app because of that? It would not the main part of the app and not even that visible.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=cartoon+characters+copyright

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/fair-use/info